# Bootup Receiver in Android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it possible to show a notification in android wear after the system has been restarted. I can see Weather notification comes up automatically after the android wear is restarted.

I would like to get my app's notification to come up the same way? Is there a bootup receiver?

Is this possible? if so how?

Thanks!

Comment: BTW. If you're asking a question please at least show ANY effort you've made in order to find a solution on your own. Questions like "code it for me" are not very welcome. You even know all words to do a search for that: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+boot+receiver.

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga I know how to implement for android mobile app but I didn't know how to do the same for Android wear? I tried the same code but didn't work for me.

Comment: In your question you haven't wrote anything about things you've tried so far, so no one will know about your efforts. Android wear is basically a normal Android OS. I've just tried my code and it works perfectly fine on Android Wear. My BroadcastReceiver receives an intent after about 15 seconds after boot. Probably some other receivers delay the intent for that time. After increasing priority of intent-filter the intent is receiver immediately after boot. So as you can see everything works fine with my code - you  have probably did something wrong in your code. Please try it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanism is the same as on standard Android devices. Please follow these steps:

Create your `MyBootCompletedReceiver` in Java code:

```
public class MyBootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // do your things - show notification for example
        }
    }
}
```

Add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Register a receiver in your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBootCompletedReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: In my mobile App I haven't added Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction() it is working properly. in my wear app I added the above and it started working..Thanks!

Comment: This should make any difference, without this check it will work the same way. However I like to add this (even if there is only one action declared in manifest) because you don't need to look in the manifest to see what intents can be received by this BroadcastReceiver:)